# Gravity Forms - Uploading Files as Post Attachments

Tags: wordpress, customization, gravity-forms-plugin

is there a way to show uploaded file (PDF) as a Post attachments using Gravity Forms? I've created a form and added:

- Post Field > Category
- Post Field > Title
- Advanced Field > File Upload

Currently, within the post, only the "Title" and "Category" are showing.

I'm planning to use Gravity Forms to Create User-Submitted Posts that shows the following:

- Title
- Date Uploaded / Category
- Document Thumbnail
- Download Link (Document Icon | Document Size)

I did some research online and found out that with a combination of Gravity Forms with some addons or plugin, I might be able to implement this:

- Gravity Forms + Custom Post Types
- Gravity Forms + ACF

Anyone can point me to the right direction on which is the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Gravity Forms Media Library](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-media-library/) and [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/spivurno/400fc922adbbd5a36184dcfab3be21e2) will allow you to upload any file to the media library and automatically attach it to the newly created posts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems that I need to purchase "Gravity Perks" in order to get the "Gravity Forms Media Library". Any idea on how to implement this feature for free?